# How to map jsp class in web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I am trying to map my compiled jsp class which is available in org.apache.jsp folder in tomcat server folder to the web.xml file so that I don't want to ship my jsp code.

I am using following code, but getting **HTTP Status 404 -**. I cross checked, paths are correct and class files are also available in that path I don't know why i am getting this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"   
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"> 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Can any one help me to fix this?

Comment: What is the path to the jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use **jsp-file** tag for jsp mapping in web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"> 

<servlet>
<servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/index_jsp.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: @KVK:-what is your URL?which you write in the browser's url bar?

Comment: @KVK :-if you want to access jsp file directly than your url should be like this localhost:8082/your application's root folder/your file name.extension

Comment: if i add your code in web.xml then my server unable to start what can i do

Comment: @KVK:-my code does'nt create effect on server statup.it is your server problem.you can remove your server and add again.do this only if you know.or you may clean your project.try these two solution.i think this is your internal server problem