# How to WEB-INF jsp page from top level

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

[Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfBku.png)
i am trying to run below code to post the data from index.jsp page to item.jsp page but i am getting 404 not found error. I tried to create servlet but i can not create with @WebServlet annotation due to the older  version.
Is there a way to transfer the PARAM from top level jsp to root level without servlet and if not than please guide how to create servlet

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>GoogleMap</title>



  <style>
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }
    #container {
      position: relative;
      
    }
    #vertical-center {
     margin: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     color:black;
     background-color: lightblue;
     
     -ms-transform: translateY(-10%);
     transform: translateY(-50%);
}

    #map  {
      border: 2px solid rgb(14, 13, 13);
  border-radius: 5px;
     
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var lat = 51.4823
    var lng = 0.0512

    var updatedCoordsArray ={};
    var url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    var searchcoords = decodeURIComponent(url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1));
    searchcoords=searchcoords+'$sites'
   // console.log(searchcoords);
 
    var fildmarkertype= searchcoords.split('$')[1];
  //  console.log(fildmarkertype);
    searchcoords=searchcoords.split('$')[0]
    var coordspair = searchcoords.split('&');
  //  console.log(coordspair);
    var Objcoords = new Array();
    var coords = new Array();
    movedMarkers = new Hash();
    for (var i = 1; i < coordspair.length; i++) {
      var spl = coordspair[i].split('=');
     
      Objcoords[i - 1] = spl;
      coords[i - 1] = spl[1];
    }
    var uk = new Array();
    console.log(uk.toString());
    function initMap() {
      var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true
      });

      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      var maker, i;
      for (i = 0; i < Objcoords.length; i = i + 3) {
        var pointStr = Objcoords[i][1];
        var infowindowText = Objcoords[i + 2][1];
        var markerId = Objcoords[i+1][1];
    
        var poinsli = pointStr.substring(1, pointStr.length - 1).split(',');
        lat = parseFloat(poinsli[0]);
        lng = parseFloat(poinsli[1]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          map: map,
          draggable: true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          info: infowindowText,
          markerId:markerId
        });
       
      

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          console.log(infowindowText);
          console.log(this.markerId);
          infoWindow.setContent(this.info);
          infoWindow.open(map, this);
       
        })
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (marker) {
          var latLng = marker.latLng;
           console.log(latLng.lat());
      //    console.log(latLng.lng());
      //    console.log(this.markerId);
      
            movedMarkers.set(this.markerId,"^"+latLng.lng()+"^"+latLng.lat()+"^|");
        
        });
        
      }
    
        
    }
    function submitForm() {
        var newMarkerCoords = "";
          var theKeys = movedMarkers.keys();
          console.log("Type "+fildmarkertype);
              for (var i = 0; i < theKeys.length; i++) {
            
         
                     newMarkerCoords += theKeys[i] + "^" + movedMarkers.get(theKeys[i]);
              }
          console.log("newMarkerCoords "+newMarkerCoords);
    
          document.forms["imcoords"]["newMarkerCoords"].value = newMarkerCoords; 
         document.forms["imcoords"]["fildmarkertype"].value = fildmarkertype;   
          
 
        
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/TestProjectForJSP/WEB-INF/000010/item.jsp", true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var params = "newMarkerCoords=" + newMarkerCoords+"&fildmarkertype="+fildmarkertype; 
            http.send(params);
           
            http.onload = function() {
  
            console.log(http.responseText);
            
    }
          var nam = '<%=(String) application.getAttribute("newMarkerCoods") %>'
            
     
        
         console.log(nam);
                
             
    }
    

  </script>

  <script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**********************&callback=initMap">
  </script>

        <form name="imcoords">
    
                 <input type="hidden"   name="newMarkerCoords"> 
                 <input type="hidden"   name="fildmarkertype"> 
        
     
     
    
                <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitForm()">Submit Coords </button>
        </form>
        

</body>
</html>
```

tried JSP forwarding but didnt work

Comment: The WEB-INF folder is not accessable to the public. You need to map item.jsp in your web.xml file.

Comment: Sorry rickz how to map it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541258/how-to-map-jsp-class-in-web-xml